# Newest windows 10 causes massive frame drops

Tags: windows-10, fps

So yesterday I decided to update my computer, I didn't think that much about it, I just told it to update and shut down.

So today when I came on my computer it of course had to finish up the updates, and then I could get on.

So as soon as I started playing, I could feel that it was almost impossible, due to massive lag.

As I was playing CS:GO as the first game, I would have to make sure that it wasn't because it was a big game, so I went on Minecraft, and again, massive lag.

So after some time I realised that it was not only my games, but pretty much every process that was laggy, and even opening my browser gave me high CPU usage.

Since the computer was working just fine yesterday, I came to the conclusion that it was due to the new update, and I took it to here.

I hope you guys can help!

Comment: Have you uninstalled KB3194496 to verify the problem is the update or a driver issue?  CS:GO and Minecraft are both OpenGL applications.

Comment: @Ramhound No I haven't, will try

Comment: @Ramhound No difference. Does that mean that it wasn't the update?

Comment: Yes; it means it's a driver issue

Comment: @Ramhound And do you know how that can be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

Had same problem a couple of weeks back on my laptop. All applications using discrete Nvidia card would experience sudden freezes now and then.
Got it resolved by reinstalling graphics card drivers and then chipset drivers.